# What is this ⌅ symbol?

Tags: macos, pages

[image]

As you can see in the image, there is a symbol that looks like a caret under a horizontal line.

I want to break page by this shortcut in the image but I don’t know what the second symbol is and where it is on the keyboard. Please help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the unicode symbols for Mac functional keys? (Command, Shift, etc.)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55727/where-can-i-find-the-unicode-symbols-for-mac-functional-keys-command-shift-e)

Comment: @Alper - no, not a dupe. 'What physical key is this on my keyboard?" not 'How do I generate this symbol?"

Comment: Here's explained very well. TLDR; Different keys actually; keyboard which has numeric keypad, that's the enter symbol for it. Source: https://superuser.com/questions/522743/what-is-the-keyboard-symbol-on-a-mac

Answer (score 31):

## ⌅

is a symbol representing a press of the Enter key.
Enter is [often confused with return](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47567/5472) ↩ and less often with control due to the caret.

## ⌃

is the Control symbol.

So your keyboard shortcut is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>

<sup>I had to space everything out to persuade SE to draw them large.</sup>

*From Comments*
Enter & Return are *distinct* keys but their functionality is not often differentiated.
If you specifically need Enter for a function on a short [laptop] keyboard with only a Return key, then  <kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>  will send Enter.

Comment: What's the difference between Return and Enter?

Comment: @justhalf Originally, [Carriage Return vs Line Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return). But now they both behave like a CR+LF - move to the start of the next line.

Comment: @justhalf -  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/47565/85275 for a more Mac-specific explanation - I know Adobe & FCP still differentiate functionally. Fn/Return will give Enter if needed.